# Dynamic field names in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to create a checkbox in Laravel 5.1 with a name like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="groups[1]">
<input type="checkbox" name="groups[2]">
```

I am using the following code, but it doesn't work.  Does anyone know the correct way to code this?

```
{!! Form::checkbox('groups[{{ $user->id }}]', 'administrator', in_array('Administrator', $user->roles()->lists('name')->toArray())) !!}
```

The output I get is:

```
<input checked="checked" name="groups[<?php echo e($user->email); ?>]" value="administrator" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: What error / output you got ?

Comment: I have just posted the output above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use blade inside php. Just concatinate the `id` as normal.

Try this:

```
Form::checkbox('groups['.$user->id.']', 'administrator', in_array('Administrator', $user->roles()->lists('name')->toArray())) !!}
```

Comment: You probably mean to say you can't use Blade in Blade

Comment: Well, arguments of checkbox method are PHP. :)

Comment: Correct, but it's being rendered inside a blade `{!! !!}` block. OP post equated to `{!! {$var} !}}`